# Getting high gas error when trying to add liquidity spookyswap testnet

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, tokens, erc-20

[image]

Getting high gas error when trying to add liquidity

Contract of token https://testnet.ftmscan.com/token/0x21eDdDA49BB1625ae356E452df180D11244735Fb

spookyswap UniswapV2Router02 testnet
https://testnet.ftmscan.com/address/0xa6ad18c2ac47803e193f75c3677b14bf19b94883#writeContract

address used

0xCEa9A70C5F192EFC560a8101f8DeD5e01222Ca2C

Answer (score 0):

you don't have enough `allowance`.

You need to approve the smart contract to use your token by calling:
`function approve(address spender, uint amount)`

you can call `approve` on your ERC20(0x21eDdDA49BB1625ae356E452df180D11244735Fb)

with SpookyswapRouter as `spender` : `0xa6AD18C2aC47803E193F75c3677b14BF19B94883`

and `amount` should be the amount you want to deposit(you can put a higher amount to be sure)